# git clone can't resolve proxy

Tags: git

When I try to clone from git

```
git clone "http://github.com/symfony/symfony.git" "d:/www/a/vendor/symfony"
```

I get an error

```
Cloning into 'd:/www/a/vendor/symfony'...
error: Couldn't resolve proxy '(null)' while accessing http://github.com/symfony/symfony.git/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

I'm connected directly to the internet (without proxy). I tried to turn off firewall and didn't help. I'm on windows and just installed Git-1.7.10-preview20120409.exe from http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list . Previously I had 1.7.8 and this command worked. I also reinstalled TortoiseGit but I think it doesn't matter.

My `C:\Documents and Settings\xxx\.gitconfig` file is

```
[http]
    proxy = 
[user]
    name = xxxx
    email = xxx@example.com
```

Comment: the command worked for me so it has to be something with your settings. did you start the cmd.exe with administration rights? do you have a proxy program running or any kind of software to anonymize your system?

Comment: I don't have any proxy running and I tried all this with admin rights. I can push changes using TortoiseGit

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Seems the problem is reported in the mailing list.
Does [this](http://osdir.com/ml/msysgit/2012-04/msg00054.html) help?

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
```

Comment: I added my file "c:\Documents and Settings\xxx\.gitconfig" to the question body.

Comment: thanks man. this helped me at my office under firewall. Solved the bower proxy issue too

Comment: Awesome! I had a problem with my work laptop VPN'ing into my work network and came across this answer that saved me a lot of time!

Comment: This helped me, almost 4 years after this answer. I can't git clone with http.proxy, but I can't git commit without it. Office proxies. Can't live with it, can't live without...my salary :(

Comment: did not work for me. still screams `could not resolve proxy: cloud-proxy.shaharma.net`

Comment: the link is broken

Answer (score 10):

Run the below command in git bash

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
```

**Note: Don't forget to restart the git bash, otherwise it won't work.**

Also make sure to remove HTTPS_PROXY and HTTP_PROXY environment variables.

---

If the above steps didn't work for you, try setting your companies proxy as shown below;

```
git config --global  http://example.com:8080
git config --global  https://example.com:8080
```

**change example.com/8080 with your companies proxy and port

Comment: I am thanking you for the solution "remove HTTPS_PROXY and HTTP_PROXY environment variables."

Comment: The note to restart the git bash fixed it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I just got the same issue, when pushing behind a firewall.

The problem wasn't an empty http_proxy var (git var -l didn't show any proxy variable), and my OS environment variables included:

```
http_proxy=username:passowrd@proxy.company:port
https_proxy=username:passowrd@proxy.company:port
no_proxy=.company
```

This setting would always trigger a:

```
error: Couldn't resolve proxy '(null)' while accessing https://...
```

However, as soon I changed the proxy variables, **adding an '`http://`' in front of the proxy addresses, the error message stopped**:

```
http_proxy=http://username:passowrd@proxy.company:port
https_proxy=http://username:passowrd@proxy.company:port
no_proxy=.company
```

(note the '`http://`' even for the https proxy address)

Answer (score 7):

Just delete the

```
 [http]
     proxy =
```

worked for me

Comment: Where can those lines be found? I am working with TortoiseGit and none of the config files I found in the `.git` directory seemed to have anything named `[http]` or `proxy`.

Comment: You should be able to find them in your ~/.gitconfig file.  Check this out too: (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#FILES)

Comment: Thanks. My problem is solved. 
I used git config --global --unset http.proxy and your answer.

Answer (score 5):

I have two work environments, when I'm at the company and when I'm at home. So, every single day I have to set and unset proxy variables to get my git running. What I found efficient was to create two bash files, one for setting the proxy variables and another one for "unsetting" it. So, whenever I arrive home or at work, all I have to do is to double click the files with admin rights and I'm done. The files are really simple:

**unset-proxy.bat**

```
setx HTTP_PROXY ""
setx HTTPS_PROXY ""
setx HTTP_PROXY "" /M
setx HTTPS_PROXY "" /M
git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --global --unset https.proxy
sleep 5
```

**set-proxy.bat**

```
setx HTTP_PROXY <your proxy here>
setx HTTPS_PROXY <your proxy here>
setx HTTP_PROXY <your proxy here> /M
setx HTTPS_PROXY <your proxy here> /M
git config --global <your proxy here>
git config --global <your proxy here>
sleep 5
```

The `sleep 5` at the end is only to keep the window open for some seconds to verify if all commands ran correctly.

Comment: It's working for my office laptop.. 
Thanks for sharing the knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @VonC for the answer.

Though it dint work for me your way, I used your answer as reference to have my work-around.

I had configured below environment variables to solve one of the cloud foundry dev environment issue. And all of sudden my git clone raised alarms saying couldn't resolve proxy. I just removed these environment variables and git clone working well.

```
http_proxy=proxy.company:port
https_proxy=proxy.company:port
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: 6 years later (after my original answer): great! Well done.

Answer (score 2):

Just delete the

```
 [http]
     proxy =
```

block in the Git global config file. (git version 1.7.10.msysgit.1 , windows XP)

The command line command mentioned in positron's answer doesn't work:

```
 git config --global --unset http.proxy

 error: unknown switch `â'
```

Comment: Seems like you re inputting some wrong switch. It never said to me like that, and for anyone too ;)

Comment: Thanks for your input, yes, there is a wrong switch in your above command line. "-–unset" the second switch is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Type the following commands.

1. `git config --global http.proxy example.com:8080`

   Here, `example.com` is the proxy server and `8080` is the port number.
2. See to that you have set the proxy server.
3. Then, do cloning the required repository. It will work.

I tried these in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

First try to reset the Github proxy. Sometimes it might be issue with proxy server.

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
```

Then restart the terminal and try again to clone the repository.

If still you are getting error, then you have to try to set the proxy using the following command.

```
git config --global http.proxy http://proxyUsername:proxyPassword@proxy.server.com:port
```

Answer (score 0):

the proxy should start with "http" or "https"

e.g.

```
abc.proxy.com:8080 may not work
http://abc.proxy.com:8080 should work
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with running git on CentOS 6.5.  Running the same command on Ubuntu worked fine.  Git seemed to have a problem with the colon in the url. Anyway, the solution ended up being that I had to explicitly specify the port in the url, e.g.:

```
git clone https://example.edu.au:443/git/master.git
```

Answer (score 0):

This error comes because Proxy which is you used. Even you add Proxy setting to your PC there will be some errors. Because the system setting changing is not enough to GIT. So your should config git for proxy.

```
git config --global http.proxy http://proxyUsername:proxyPassword@proxy.server.com:port
```

Here proxyUsername is the user name that you use and proxyPassword is its password. proxy.server.com means proxy server name and port is the port that use for proxy.
If you use specific Domain use this code :

```
git config --global http.https://domain.com.proxy http://proxyUsername:proxyPassword@proxy.server.com:port
```

Answer (score 0):

when you use this command on Ubuntu, use 'sudo' to get administrative permission in the begging of 'git clone'

ex-: sudo git clone "http://github.com/symfony/symfony.git" "d:/www/a/vendor/symfony"

Answer (score 0):

In order to activate/deactivate proxy for git, I use two shell functions in ~/.bashrc:

```
proxy_set() {
    export http_proxy=http://PROXYADDR:PORT/
    export https_proxy=https://PROXYADDR:PORT/
    export socks_proxy=socks://PROXYADDR:PORT;
    sed -i '/proxy =/s/^#//g' ~/.gitconfig
}
proxy_unset() {
    unset http_proxy; unset https_proxy; unset socks_proxy;
    sed -i '/proxy =/s/^#*/#/g' ~/.gitconfig
}
```

These will uncomment/comment the [http] and [https] proxy entries in ~/.gitconfig respectively.
Just type in the terminal, proxy_set or proxy_unset and you're all set.