# Windows 8 : git cannot push or pull or clone

Tags: windows, git

I have installed Windows 8 (before that, I use Windows 7). At Windows 7, I use git command everything normally. But I don't know why, at Windows 8, git command relates to network (push, pull or clone) cannot work anymore. For example, when I use :

```
git clone https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu
```

As some post below, I have changed to another link but still get the same error:

```
git clone https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu.git
```

I will receive this error:

```
fatal : unable to access "https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu' Could not resolve proxy : proxyaddress
```

I have googled and get some result, but when I try still cannot fix this problem.

Please tell me how to fix this. Thanks :)

Comment: I'm guessing that it's not asking you for your user/pass?

Comment: @BRogers can you tell me more detail. in fact, i just clone a repo, so I don't think anything relates to username/password here

Comment: Answered, hope that helps :)

Comment: Firewall/proxy issue. My answer (in the comments) linked to post about this exact issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The URL doesn't have to end with `.git`, this should work fine.

```
git clone https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu
```

The real problem is your proxy settings:

> fatal : unable to access "https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu' Could not resolve proxy : proxyaddress

Since the value of your proxy server is apparently "proxyaddress", it looks like a copy & pasted git configuration where you forgot to replace "proxyaddress" with the correct address of your proxy server. Either fix that in your `~/.gitconfig` or delete the proxy setting completely with:

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
```

Answer (score 0):

It has to end it .git

try this

```
git clone https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu.git
```

Example of random git clone url

```
https://github.com/joewalnes/websocketd.git
```

Comment: If you wanted to clone it into a specific name you could do `git clone https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu.git [put name of git directory you want here`

Comment: I have change to your link (although old link still works well under windows 7) but still no result

Comment: Doesn't give you an error?

Comment: it gives me same error as above

Comment: I actually tried the exact link I showed you and it worked. Are you behind a proxy? Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333836/git-clone-cant-resolve-proxy

Comment: Github https repo URLs do not have to end with `.git`. A simple test shows this.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you copied the URL wrong (it should have ended with .git). For example :https://github.com/xxxxx/xxxx.git

Make sure you are copying the full length of the URL.

Comment: I have change to your link (although old link still works well under windows 7) but still no result  and get the same error :( I have edit my post

Comment: try the steps suggested in the following link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18356502/github-failed-to-connect-to-github-443-windows-failed-to-connect-to-github

Comment: Github https repo URLs do not have to end with `.git`. A simple test shows this.