# git push -u origin master always fails

Tags: git, github

Whenever I try to use `git push -u origin master` it always fails. Is it  because of the proxy or something else? I tried adding my GitHub username and password to the Git proxy config and it still did not work.

[image]

Comment: `ping -a github.com` ? No wait, `Couldn't resolve proxy 'foo'` => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333836/git-clone-cant-resolve-proxy

Comment: i tried the git config --global --unset http.proxy, the origin master does not do anything when i hit enter

Comment: Could you recheck if you configured git to work properly with the proxy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/783811/getting-git-to-work-with-a-proxy-server ? (;

Comment: now i have "Please make sure you have the correct access rights"

Comment: Are you listed as member, contributer or owner of the github repo ?

Comment: well i created the github repository and its my account

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940626/github-error-message-permission-denied-publickey, this helps ?

Comment: Please don't post text in screenshots. They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question.