# fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git/': Could not resolve proxy: proxy-listen-ip

Tags: ios, git, proxy

My git reports error, when I `$ git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master`:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git/': Could not resolve proxy: proxy-listen-ip

How to resolve it?

Comment: This doesn't help `git config --global --unset http.proxy` ? Probable duplicate from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333836/git-clone-cant-resolve-proxy

Comment: @ASR, right. Because my pod clone is too slow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git clone can't resolve proxy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333836/git-clone-cant-resolve-proxy)

Comment: Thats the question i had pointed above :) so your issue got resolved?

Answer (score -1):

git config --global --unset http.proxy helps as @ASR suggested. Had to do git config --global --unset https.proxy too to get the issue resolved.