# Could not resolve proxy - git clone

Tags: git, github

I am working on a TensorFlow tutorial at the moment and need to download the source code. When I run `git clone ...`, however, I get the following error:

```
C:\Git\cmd>git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/nmt/
Cloning into 'nmt'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/tensorflow/nmt/': Could not resolve proxy: aproxy
```

I am working from my home network and have the latest version of Git.
I tried the following command, without success:

```
git config --global --unset https.proxy
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the proxy settings of your system?

Comment: If you are using windows, check here please: https://helpdeskgeek.com/networking/internet-connection-problem-proxy-settings/

Comment: As the website points out, everything is set to Off.

Comment: Have you tried both (not only one): `git config --global --unset http.proxy` and `git config --global --unset https.proxy`

Comment: Yes, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Can you actually browse the link in your internet browser? https://github.com/tensorflow/nmt/

Comment: Yes, the link works

Comment: I am sorry I have no more ideas, it could be that your firewall does something bad. Or some app, it could be anything. For now I would just download the source code as zip to be able to continue working.

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333836/git-clone-cant-resolve-proxy? If answers there didn't work, maybe keep an eye out for the GitHub desktop bug tracking a user experiencing the same issue: https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/3878

Answer (score 11):

Git has its own proxy.

To reset git proxy:

```
git config --global https.proxy ""
git config --global http.proxy ""
```

To reset system proxy:

On Ubuntu, you can set proxy by using

```
export http_proxy=""
export https_proxy=""

export all_proxy=""
```

Then run

```
git clone
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to your cloned repository, and type:

```
git config -l --show-origin
```

Check if you see any `http(s).proxy` setting anywhere (since git config --global --unset only takes care of one of the config files)

Check also your environment variable in the CMD session/bash you are in (`set` or `env`) and [make sure no `HTTP(S)_PROXY` variable was defined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42409521/6309).